# Scroll in grouped listview

Tags: wpf, listview, scrollbar, grouping

I'm so desperate.... to get my WPF grouped listview to work...
I'm not able to scroll within my listview...

In my example application I've a Listview with two expanders.
The first contains a lot of listviewitems... so it is neccessary to scroll...
But if I use the "damn scrollbar" it jumps directly to the next expander (in my case expander 2of2)...so it is not possible to scroll correctly...

First Screenshot:
[image: View 1]

Second Screenshot:
[image: View 2]

My ListView Style:

```
 <Style x:Key="list12" TargetType="ListView">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListView">
                <Border Name="Border" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#999999" Background="#DFDFDF">
                    <ScrollViewer Style="{DynamicResource {x:Static GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey}}">
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

My GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyle:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Static GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyleKey}" TargetType="ScrollViewer">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollViewer">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <DockPanel Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
                        <ScrollViewer DockPanel.Dock="Top" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Focusable="false">
                            <GridViewHeaderRowPresenter Margin="0,0,0,0" Columns="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.Columns,
                                RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderContainerStyle, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                ColumnHeaderTemplate="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderTemplate,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderTemplateSelector, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                AllowsColumnReorder="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.AllowsColumnReorder, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                ColumnHeaderContextMenu="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderContextMenu, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                ColumnHeaderToolTip="{Binding Path=TemplatedParent.View.ColumnHeaderToolTip, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                                SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                        <ScrollContentPresenter Name="PART_ScrollContentPresenter"
                                KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Local"
                                CanContentScroll="True" CanHorizontallyScroll="False"
                                CanVerticallyScroll="False"/>
                    </DockPanel>
                    <ScrollBar Name="PART_HorizontalScrollBar" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableWidth}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportWidth}" Value="{TemplateBinding HorizontalOffset}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedHorizontalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                    <ScrollBar Name="PART_VerticalScrollBar" Grid.Column="1" Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}"/>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

My ListViewItemContainerStyle:

```
<Style x:Key="ListViewItemContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="#ffffff" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,0,0" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                    <Border x:Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="#6FBDE8">
                        <GridViewRowPresenter VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected"  Value="true">
                            <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF143c65" />
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                            <GradientStopCollection>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF75aac7" Offset="0"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF143c65" Offset="1"/>
                                            </GradientStopCollection>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Bd" Property="Background" Value="#e0eff8" />
                        </Trigger>
                        <MultiTrigger>
                            <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Property="IsSelected" Value="true" />
                                <Condition Property="Selector.IsSelectionActive" Value="True" />
                            </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Bd">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                                        <LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                            <GradientStopCollection>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF75aac7" Offset="0"/>
                                                <GradientStop Color="#FF143c65" Offset="1"/>
                                            </GradientStopCollection>
                                        </LinearGradientBrush.GradientStops>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="Bd" Value="#FF143c65"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                        </MultiTrigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Just my Listview:

```
<ListView  Style="{StaticResource list12}" Name="ListView1" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemContainerStyle="{DynamicResource ListViewItemContainerStyle}" Margin="0,44,0,0">
                        <ListView.GroupStyle>
                            <GroupStyle>
                                <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                        <Setter Property="Template" >
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                                                    <Expander IsExpanded="true" BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" Margin="10">
                                                            <Expander.Header>
                                                            <Grid>
                                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
                                                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                                <Label Content="{Binding Path=Name}" Grid.Column="0"/>
                                                                <Label Content="{Binding Path=ItemCount}" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="2"/>
                                                            </Grid>
                                                        </Expander.Header>
                                                            <Expander.Content>
                                                                <ItemsPresenter />                                              
                                                            </Expander.Content>
                                                        </Expander>
                                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                                </Setter.Value>
                                            </Setter>
                                        </Style>
                                    </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                                </GroupStyle>
                            </ListView.GroupStyle>
                        <ListView.View>
                        <GridView>
                            <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource IDItemTemplate}" Header="ID"/>
                            <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource DateItemTemplate}" Header="Datum" />
                            <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource TypeItemTemplate}" Header="Typ" />
                            <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource StatusItemTemplate}" Header="Status" />
                            <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource AuthorItemTemplate}" Header="Autor" />
                            <GridViewColumn CellTemplate="{StaticResource BenennungItemTemplate}" Header="Benennung" />
                        </GridView>
                    </ListView.View>
                </ListView>
```

I don't know how can I solve my problem...
Hope some of you can help me to get it working...

Thank you all for your efforts.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your problem is the  `<Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>` setter property for the ListView style.

Content in a ScrollViewer can be scrolled in terms of physical units or logical units. Physical units are device independent pixels. Logical units are used for scrolling items within an ItemsControl. **(which is what you're doing now)**. The default behavior of the ScrollViewer is to use physical units to scroll its content. However, in cases where the **CanContentScroll is set to true, the content could use logical units to scroll.** For example, ListBox, ListView, and other controls that inherit from ItemsControl use logical units to scroll. If CanContentScroll is true, the values of the ExtentHeight, ScrollableHeight, ViewportHeight, and VerticalOffset properties are number of items, instead of physical units.

If you require physical scrolling instead of logical scrolling, wrap the host Panel element in a ScrollViewer and set its CanContentScroll property to false. Physical scrolling is the default scroll behavior for most Panel elements.

for more information go here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.cancontentscroll.aspx

Comment: @user1011394: I would try the ListView style Setter for the "ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" property.

Comment: The behavior is the same as before. It doesn't matter if I set it to "false" or "true"

Comment: @user1011394: set CanContentScroll="True" to CanContentScroll="false" in the GridView.GridViewScrollViewerStyle for the ScrollContentPresenter

Comment: Thank you...... it works... Thank you very much. Next time I will read the msdn documenation a little bit more exactly ;-)